# Add time to textarea after click button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time, click

When i click **id=dodaj_godzine_button** i want to add current time to **id=formularz_wpis_tresc** (as string)

I made this but it's doesn't work.

```
$("#dodaj_godzine_button").click(function(){
        var data = new Date();
        var godzina = data.getHours();
        var minuty = data.getMinutes();
        var czas = godziny;
        czas += ((minuty < 10) ? ":0" : ":");
        $("#formularz_wpis_tresc").html("Godzina: " + czas + "\n");
    });
```

Where i've made mistake?

Comment: `var czas = godziny;` should be `var czas = godzina;`.

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: Test code: http://jsfiddle.net/s9wxfzcw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("#dodaj_godzine_button").click(function(){
    var data = new Date();
    var godzina = data.getHours();
    var minuty = data.getMinutes();
    minuty = ((minuty < 10) ? ":0" + minuty : ":" + minuty);
    $("#formularz_wpis_tresc").html("Godzina: " + godzina + minuty + "\n");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the console log message you got if you take a look at the javascript console? try using

```
$("#formularz_wpis_tresc").val("Godzina: " + czas + "\n");
```

see if that works

Answer (score 0):

There where two bugs:

1- czas should be equals to "godzina" instead of "godziny".

2- The right way to show the output is:

```
$("#formularz_wpis_tresc").html("Godzina: " + czas + minuty + "\n");
```

#### Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9wxfzcw/

Answer (score 0):

Two corrections should make it work:

First, change:

```
var czas = godziny;
```

To:

```
var czas = godzina;
```

as pointed out by **@dfsq** in the comments.
Then, change:

```
$("#formularz_wpis_tresc").html("Godzina: " + czas + "\n");
```

To:

```
$("#formularz_wpis_tresc").val("Godzina: " + czas + "\n");
```

as pointed out by **@user2325727**, assuming this is the `textarea` and the clicked element is the the `button`.